# Spring Security 4 : Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, post, spring-security

The issue is that when I click on submit I get

```
Etat HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Here is the controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    LOGGER.debug("admin login page");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }

    model.setViewName("/admin/index");
    LOGGER.debug("returning admin login page");

    return model;
}
```

And the form :

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" th:action="@{/admin/login}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username and password.</div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out.</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
    <a href="#"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        <small>Do not have an account?</small>
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="register.html">Create an account</a>
</form>
```

It seems like csrf field not working.

I explain, I have normal users website which I refer here by   and admin part which is /admin

The login form is correctly displayed. But I when I click submit I get Etat `HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`

Any idea please ?

Here is my security configuration class :

```
package com.mintad.spring.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

/**
 * @author Sofiane HAMMAMI
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").permitAll()
//          .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/404");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller , you defined the form as `GET`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and in the form, you are calling it as `POST`:

```
form class="m-t" role="form" th:action="@{/admin/login}" method="POST"
```

change one of these, either at controller or in the form.

If you want to change at controller, replace existing line with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

or you can do it by modifying call from form like

```
form class="m-t" role="form" th:action="@{/admin/login}" method="GET"
```

Comment: Is wise send login data how a GET? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Reason you get 405 is, you are trying to submit your form with http post method and defined the end point with http get method.

You need to change your request mapping to method as `POST` like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

OR you could do vice versa (which is **not** recommend by security reasons) in your form like:

```
 <form class="m-t" role="form" th:action="@{/admin/login}" method="GET" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thank you @SMA.  that was the solution :)

Comment: I dont understand this @Sofiane same answer being repeated by Sidhu after an hour written by me and you accepted the one that's copied?

Comment: when I opened the oldest tab, sidhu answer appeared first. I can't see any date neither on your answer or sidhu one.

Comment: Ok its not your issue then. One way to check Sidhu wrote after this answer (7 mins later) is to click on individual names (just below answered X hours ago) and at the right just hover X hours ago and you would see..

Comment: Is wise send login data how a GET? I don't think so

Comment: @ManuelJordan agree with you and if you read the answer, I mentioned that i wouldn't recommend the same.

Comment: Agree, I did not read that part. I am going to highlight it

Answer (score 1):

Change your security config to use `/admin/login` as your login page:

```
...
.formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login")
```

Comment: this loginpage have not to be change since it will be used in the normal website part.